# Yahoo Developer Network Create App gives "Database connection failed (read-write)" Error

Tags: yahoo-api

After registering to Yahoo, from the following link I've tried to create a web-based application, but form gives "Database connection failed (read-write)" error.

https://developer.yahoo.com/apps/create/

Any idea?